# Login Form Using Google Cloud Datastore with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm new to Google App Engine and Datastore, and I'm trying to build a simple login form that checks my Datastore entities to see if the login details provided by the user matches. I'm building this form with ReactJS but I don't know how to link it with Datastore.

I installed the package `@google-cloud/datastore` but it returns a lot of errors that says it can't resolve `child_process`, `fs`, `net`, and `tls`.

[image: Errors]

I've looked for any questions similar to mine but I couldn't find any results that work for me.

How do I link my ReactJS project with Google Datastore so that I can validate the user's entered details? Thank you!

Here is my file structure.

[image: File Structure]

Here's a screenshot of my dependencies.

[image: Dependencies used]

***login.jsx***

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const { Datastore } = require("@google-cloud/datastore");

const Login = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const datastore = new Datastore({
    projectId: "XXX-XXX-123456",
  });

  // Set the page's title
  document.title = "Login | Task 1";

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = () => {
      const query = datastore
        .createQuery("user")
        .order("id", {ascending: true});

      setUsers(datastore.runQuery(query));
    };

    init();
  }, []);

  const validateInput = () => {
    // ...
  }

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <h1>Login</h1>

      <form onSubmit={validateInput}>
        <label for="id"><b>ID</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ID" name="id" required />
        <br />

        <label for="user_name"><b>Username</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="user_name" required />
        <br />

        <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required />
        <br />

        <button>Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Add some of the errors you said you encountered with ```datastore```. At what point do you get these errors?

Comment: @NoCommandLine I get the errors when running `npm start`. I've edited the question to include the screenshot of these errors.

Comment: Quick/dirty - delete your ```node_modules``` folder and run ```npm install``` again.

Comment: @NoCommandLine, that might get rid of the errors but I still don't know how to link Google Datastore with my React project

Answer (score 1):

The [`@google-cloud/datastore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/datastore) is a Client Library for `Node.js` and meant to be used on server side and not in a web application. You must also [initialise the Datastore SDK](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/client-libraries) using a service account or Application Default Credentials ADC.

You can use [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to use Datastore and call it from your web app as shown below:

```
// Cloud Function
exports.functionName = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // read/write from Datastore
});

// Call the function from web app
const fnName = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('functionName');
fnName({})
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data);
  });
```

If possible, you can upgrade to [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore) and then use [Firebase Client SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) that can be used directly on client side.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Google App Engine and Datastore consider using [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints). Cloud Endpoints is an API interface that will run on App Engine and allow you to access Datastore, Google Cloud Storage and other server-side APIs.

Another simpler option is to use [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore). Firestore is more heavy on client-side code but have the auto-scaling features of App Engine as well.